# Simple onClick effect in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a very simple web page. Here is my [Demo](http://jsbin.com/adacot/10/edit).

**Desktop:** When I hover over the circle, it expands.

**iPad:** When I click the circle, it expands.

However, is it possible (on iPad) that when the circle is in the "expanded" state, if I click it again, it contracts?

How would I do this using my existing code?

**Javascript:**

```
$('.circle').on('touchstart',function(){});
```

Many thanks for any help with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var events = "mouseover mouseout";
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad)/)) {
    events = "touchstart";
};

$('.circle').on(events,function(){
   if ($(this).hasClass("expanded")) {
       // contract the circle
       $(this).addClass("contracted").removeClass("expanded");
   } else {
       // expand the circle
       $(this).addClass("expanded").removeClass("contracted");
   };
});
```

Now add `class contracted` to all your circles.

Comment: Here is my amended code: http://jsbin.com/adacot/13/edit Any ideas why it doesn't "contract" if I click it when open?

Comment: Thanks for this. What would you recommend I change this to?

Comment: Thanks sir. I'm fairly new to Javascript as you can possibly tell. Would you be able to put together an example using my jsbin code?

Comment: Yep, I'm not a big fan of jsbin either, but jsfiddle was down for me earlier :'( I've noticed the 'hover' is now disabled on Desktop. Is there a way to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

I would try using jQuery toggle: http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

```
$('.circle').toggle(function() {
  $(this).addClass("expanded").removeClass("contracted");
}, function() {
  $(this).removeClass("expanded").addClass("contracted");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Vytautas. Can you show me using my code how I would implement this? Should I change my HTML?